# Not able to SSH in Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: ssh, windows, dhcp, static-ip

I'm trying to SSH into my RPi 3. Its connected to my WiFi network and has the IP 192.168.0.103. I previously used it over a direct lan connection to my old Win 8.1 PC, running the `hostname -I` command gave me an IP with which I could connect to my Pi over SSH and I got a VNC server running as well.

I've had some upgrades lately and bought a new PC, Win 10. I've checked the IP of the Pi from both the router and the `hostname -I` command on the RPi, both show the same IP as above. But whenever I try to SSH into it using puTTY it gives me an error

> Connection timed out.

I can't even ping the IP from command prompt, it says destination host unreachable, but I receive all the packets sent. And sometimes the same error pops up on puTTY.

I am able to ssh into the Pi over a direct lan connection, but not through my router.

I suspect port forwarding is the issue here, but I don't know much about it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39299/discussion-on-question-by-yaddyvirus-not-able-to-ssh-in-raspberry-pi-3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to turn of AP Isolation on my WiFi router. Did that and problem solved!!